# How to add rows base on the specified number on textbox vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Hello everyone I'm new at making app using vue.js
I'm wondering How to add rows base on the specified number on textbox.

this is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/7nxhygLp/2/

> script

```
    var evaluate  = new Vue({
  el: "#evaluate",
  data: {
    rows: [
    ]
  },
  methods:{
    addRow: function(){
      this.rows.push({});
    },
    removeRow: function(row){
      //console.log(row);
      this.rows.$remove(row);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `v-model` to retrieve the value of the input box, and then just push that many new rows:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" v-model="rowCount" name="rows" class="rows-textbox">
```

**JS**

```
data: {
    rowCount:0,
    rows: [
    ]
  },
  methods:{
    addRow: function(){
      for(i = 0; i < this.rowCount; i++){
        this.rows.push({});
      }
      this.rowCount = 0;
    },
  }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7nxhygLp/5/)